# How are big (Node.js) single page projects implemented?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am currently doing my first project, which is a single page with a big backend background.
There are 5 full scrolls of 1920x1080 monitor of HTML (a.k.a 1 scroll = 1 page block). I have it as a project with no backend, no templates, nothing.
There is a second, back-end based project, which is supposed to go in the first one as just another block.

Now is the time to merge them into one.

But it is just an enormous amount of html, which I fear to lose myself in. Even for the backend-based project, which brings me to **the question**:

How are these heavy-html projects made? Only with template engines like handlebars, or are there other methods? What is the most efficient way? If it only uses a template engine, does it just generate a biiiig html from different parts and serve it to the user?

Comment: where did you get front-end project from? what have you tried? what is the project about? why do you want to merge both projects?. So you know, a 5 page app is not a heavy-html project. It is actually tiny

Comment: I wrote both. First - html-part, I learned backend heavily for last 2 months, It is about 1000 lines now, I want to be able to break it into parts for simpler modification and reusability. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to choose a way of communication between the both. Usually JSON is the preferred way (search google about it). You send the data from back-end to front-end in this format so they "speak" the same "language" so to speak.

Second, if it is a big project as you say (1000 lines of code is not that big) I suggest organizing you back-end into smaller parts. How? It depends. For example, if you have a blog application you can organize the back-end into 1 small file that gives the list of blog post, another file that gives the list of blog categories etc. This way you organize your files to serve a resource at a time.

Usually big projects are organizes using patterns, like MVC(Model-View-Controller)
- Model -> makes a connection with your databae
- View -> here is where the html comes. This is the visual part
- Controller -> links the 2 above

Take a look at express.js on how it organizes the project. Make a small app using it. Take a look at sails.js and try to make a small project with it too. Also, take a look at meteor.js and make a project too. This way you will learn how they organize projects:

- folder structure
- task runners
- database structure
- code style
- package management
- workflow
- etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use express's "static" setting to serve the html to the user. And was thinking about using the handlebars template engine to ease the process of this. What I was actually interested is - is it all there is to constructing reusabe html, that can be separated into different files, or is there something else?

Comment: Using a template engine is the best way of going (almost every major framework uses this)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest sth. like Vue.js for organizing your HTML. As it uses plain HTML for its templates, its probably a good choice for what you're aiming. 
Start with some broader Components and as soon as you realize, that you have duplicate code parts, refactor them to smaller components.